# Run Django in production or development mode and let variables depend on it

Tags: python, django

I'm working on a Django project and in one of my functions I'm redirecting the user to a redirect url which is different in production and development. When the project is running in production, it's starting up the server with the wsgi.py file and gunicorn. When I'm developing I start up the server with `python manage.py runserver`. So I figured I can just initialise environment variable `'DEVELOPMENT_MODE'='FALSE'` and then evaluate `os.environ.get('DEVELOPMENT_MODE')` in the py file where I have the redirect url, since this environment variable will not be initialised with `python manage.py runserver`. This doesn't seem to be working though and I'm looking for a solution. This is my first project in Django.

The env var is set in wsgi.py like this:

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'spotifycluster.settings')
os.environ.setdefault('DEVELOPMENT_MODE', 'TRUE')
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

and then the credentials.py, where the variables exist that need to depend on the env var, looks like this:

```
import os

CLIENT_ID = "xxxx"
CLIENT_SECRET = "xxxx"

if os.environ.get('DEVELOPMENT_MODE') == 'TRUE':
    REDIRECT_URI = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/spotify/redirect'
    URL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/'
else:
    REDIRECT_URI = 'http://nameless-taiga-02413.herokuapp.com/spotify/redirect'
    URL = 'http://nameless-taiga-02413.herokuapp.com/'
```

I import the REDIRECT_URI and URL and use them here:

```
def get(self, request, format=None):
     url = Request('GET', 'https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize', params={
            'client_id': CLIENT_ID,
            'redirect_uri': REDIRECT_URI,
            'scope': scope,
            'response_type': 'code',
        }).prepare().url
```

and

```
def spotify_callback(request, format=None):
    ...
    return redirect(URL)
```

Comment: Can you show your function and the example urls that you would want to redirect to in certain enviroments?

Comment: Of course. I elaborated my question.

Comment: Are these the URL;s of where your django app is running? or these are urls external of the django app?

Comment: These URL’s are where the app is running. So either on the localhost URL in dev and the Heroku URL in prod.

Comment: Django will be aware of that, Generally you dont declare the full url, you would just declare say the name of one of your url,s from your urls file and django will take care of constructing the URL for you

Comment: So how would I redirect to a URL that depends on dev/prod mode?

Comment: So if you check out https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/shortcuts/#examples. Here you can return your redirect like `return redirect('/spotify/redirect')`. and django should take care of appending it to the url where the app is running

Comment: The idea is that you can run the same django app on any hosts and you shouldnt need to hardocode the urls, django takes care of it for you.

Comment: Cool, that makes sense. However, there is one other spot where I pass the REDIRECT_URI as a request parameter. It still seems logical to me to determine the URL and REDIRECT_URL based on an environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes `DEBUG` from `settings.py` is being used for that. You can make view that redirects for another view depending on that setting.

Comment: How would I import that value in another py file?

Comment: `from django.conf import settings` then `settings.DEBUG` - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/settings/#using-settings-in-python-code